# Emberjs renders the wrong template in a nested route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a nested route that looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('comment', {path: '/:commentId'}, function(){
        this.route('edit');
    });
});
```

In my markup, I have a `{{#linkTo 'comment.edit' content}}` which correctly transitions and updates the URL. However, the wrong template is displaying. Instead of getting the 'edit' template, it displays the 'index' template. This only seems to be occurring in the nested route of dynamic resources. All other nested routes render the correct template. Has anyone else run into this issue in Emberjs?

Comment: could you update with how your templates are named?

Comment: Sure. My template structure looks like this: comment/index and comment/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have attached a twiddle, which works fine for me.

https://ember-twiddle.com/a2f91851a451a5da953a